# Reject input if the adjacent cell is empty

Tags: validation, google-sheets

Using below formula to Reject input if the adjacent cell is empty.

I am trying to made the condition for the Data validation rules that if `R2:R500` is empty then Column M will Reject the input when try to add anything but below formula is not working in Validation.

```
=NOT(ISBLANK(R24))
```

Here is my [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZIdYKMvHuEhFtsbffbI24L1xqJl33RPLn-Mem5UjZoE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This works fine for me. What about your validation is working differently to the way you expect?

Comment: Its not working i want to stop adding anything in the cell if adjacent cell is empty.

Comment: But that's what this does?

Comment: Nope its not doing. I do not know why.

Comment: [Works with no issue for me](https://imgur.com/OpYx9NR)

Comment: I tried it in new sheet its working but not in my original sheet

Comment: I got the problem I am adding dates in the cell and those are entering without any problem but any other text cannot be added. what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this validation setup.

```
=$R2:$R500<>""
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But its not avoiding the cell to be edit. Formula should stop adding anything in the cell if Column R cell is empty. Reject Input is not working with this formula.

Comment: What is your apply range. Formula range and apply must must be same.

Comment: Both are same https://ibb.co/hRj6qLg

Comment: You used `=` operator but it would be not equal `<>` operator like `=$R3:$R600<>""`

Comment: Oh yes but this `=` and this `<>` have same problem both are not working.

Comment: I have added sheet please look into this

Comment: Can you please check now your sheet.